# How to run docker command in this Airflow docker container?

Tags: docker, dockerfile, airflow

I have set up Airflow with docker-compose as described here.
https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/start/docker.html

And there is a airflow task that have to execute docker command like

```
BashOperator(
    task_id='my',
    bash_command="""
        docker run ..............
    """,
    dag=dag,
)
```

This means Docker package required [in the airflow docker image, but there is not](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/Dockerfile).

So, I tried to build my own `airflow image based docker installed image`. like,

```
FROM apache/airflow:2.0.1 as airflow-image
SHELL ["/bin/bash", "-o", "pipefail", "-e", "-u", "-x", "-c"]

USER root
RUN apt-get update && apt-get --assume-yes install \
    apt-transport-https \
    ca-certificates \
    curl \
    gnupg \
    lsb-release
RUN curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/debian/gpg | sudo gpg --dearmor -o /usr/share/keyrings/docker-archive-keyring.gpg
RUN echo $(lsb_release -cs)
RUN echo \
  "deb [arch=amd64 signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/docker-archive-keyring.gpg] https://download.docker.com/linux/debian \
  $(lsb_release -cs) stable" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list > /dev/null
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get --assume-yes install docker-ce docker-ce-cli containerd.io
```

With an image of above Dockerfile, docker is installed like,

```
$ whereis docker
docker: /usr/bin/docker /usr/libexec/docker
$ whereis dockerd
dockerd: /usr/bin/dockerd
```

But I can not make docker daemon started so that task of airflow can execute `docker run` command.

After I see this ENTRYPOINT and tested several things,
https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/Dockerfile#L535

```
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/bin/dumb-init", "--", "/entrypoint"]
```

I wonder whether I can start docker daemon or not.

Any advice?
Can I make an docker image which is based airflow:2.0.1 and support docker commans?

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly you are trying to run a custom Docker image as a task in Airflow.
There is a [DockerOperator](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-docker/stable/_api/airflow/providers/docker/operators/docker/index.html) available, see an example [here](https://livebook.manning.com/concept/apache-airflow/dockeroperator).
I think what you tried to do is to host Docker inside of a Docker container. This is not necessary, since the Airflow Docker container should have access to Docker running on your machine.

So if you run Airflow 2.0 make sure to install this Python package `apache-airflow-backport-providers-docker` in your Airflow Docker container. And include this in your Python DAG file: `from airflow.providers.docker.operators.docker import DockerOperator`.
Then use the operator, something like this:

```
dockertask = DockerOperator(
                task_id='docker_command',
                image='centos:latest',
                api_version='auto',
                auto_remove=True,
                command="/bin/sleep 30",
                docker_url="unix://var/run/docker.sock",
                network_mode="bridge"
        )
```

Comment: When I run your `dockertask` from Airflow (which is in docker container that created by docker-compose instruction https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/start/docker.html) it fails with `docker.errors.DockerException: Error while fetching server API version: ('Connection aborted.', FileNotFoundError(2, 'No such file or directory'))`. Is DockerOperator operates even there is no running docker daemon? `$ pwd
/var/run
$ ls
docker-ssd.pid lock  saslauthd  utmp`